# While Loop with two conditions in MIPS

Tags: assembly, while-loop, mips

I am learning MIPs assembly language these days and I am being asked to implement the following C code in MIPS in an assignment.

```
int i = 0;
int j = 10;

while(i < 5 && j >= 5)
 {
   int sum = i+j;
   printf(“%d ”, sum);

   i++;
   j--;
 }
```

I can not understand how to implement the while loop with two conditions in MIPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written this code for you:

```
 .data   
     space: .asciiz " "
 .text
 .globl main
 .ent main
 main:
     
     li $t0, 0   #store i's value in $t0
     li $t1, 10  #store j's value in $t1
     li $t6, 5
     
     j while
     
 .end main

 #while loop
 while:
     sge $t2, $t0, $t6       #$t2=1(true) if i>=5
     slt $t3, $t1, $t6      #$t3=1(true) if j<5
     or $t4, $t3, $t2
     beq $t4, 1, exit    #exit, if $t4=1(true)
     add $t5, $t1, $t0   #sum of i and j
     
     #printing sum
     li $v0, 1
     move $a0, $t5
     syscall
     
     li $v0, 4
     la $a0, space
     syscall
     
     
     add $t0, $t0, 1     #incrementing i
     sub, $t1, $t1, 1    #decrementing j
     j while
     
 .end while
 
 exit:
     li $v0, 10
     syscall
```

The **sge**(set greater than equal) and **slt**(set less than) instructions are comparison instructions which I have used to execute the negation of two conditions so that my code knows when to exit the while loop. The Boolean values of the two conditions implemented using **sge slt** instructions are stored in $t2 and $t3 registers respectively. **or** instruction is used because of De Morgan's Law ( !(A and B) = !A or !B) for the final Boolean value of the two conditions. **beq** instruction is used to check the two conditions as whole and to determine whether to continue while loop or terminate it. If the loop is to be continued the sum of i and j is calculated and printed, and i is incremented and j is decremented using **add** and **sub** instructions.'j while' instruction in the last make sure the while loop keeps running until the conditions no longer meet.
Comments are added to the code to make sure you understand what I have done properly. I encourage you to read more about the instructions I have used and other MIPS instructions here: https://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/140/lectures/Day_3/mips_summary.pdf

Hoping this helps!

Comment: You have not implemented a function, just a single large `main`.

Comment: oh yes, thanks for letting me know. Corrected it.